# Could our universe still work if either one of $c$, $h$, $q$, $G$, permeativity, permeability or $H_o$ were slightly different?

Tags: cosmology, standard-model, space-expansion, big-bang, physical-constants

Could our universe still work if either one of c, h, G, q, permeativity, permeability or Ho were slightly different? Also all of them are thought of as being constants for the whole history of the universe except Ho (the Hubble constant) but does this imply the universe was born as a engineered creation?

Comment: You should focus on dimensionless constants, like the fine structure constant. The ones you have listed simply define your units, not actual physics.